# The variable does not update for some reason?

Tags: python, passwords

```
pss = input("Enter a password")
symb = ["!","£","$","%","^","&"]
num = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
done = 0#to break symbol check
done2 = 0#break num check
check = 0#keep track of things correct
found = False


while found == False:
    #checks for a symbol in the password
    for ch in pss:
        done = done + 1
        if ch in symb:
            check = check + 1
            break
        elif done == len(pss):#done , only to say once
            print("Add a symbol to your password")

    #WORKS!! :D



    #checks for number in password

    for ch in pss:
        done2 = done2 + 1
        if ch in num:
            check = check + 1
            break
        elif done2==len(pss):
            print("Add a number to your password")



    #capital letter check

    if pss == pss.lower():
        print("You need to have at least one capital letter")
    else:
        check = check + 1







    #checking
    if check == 3:
        print("Password Validated")
        found = True
    else:
        pss = input("Correct you password")#re enters password
        check = 0

    #need to make pss update correctly
```

Its the final few lines that I am having trouble with, the program works, its just that the password doesn't get updated, so unnecessary lines are printed. For example, when entering the initial password "Jellybean" i get reminded to add a number and a symbol to the password. Next, when i get the oppouruntiy to correct, I enter "Jellybean5£" and I still get prompted to add a number and a symbol. However the program recognizes the change and exits, due to the password being successful .

Comment: You never reset the `done` and `done2` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `done` and `done2` variables back to 0 when you're trying to validate

```
        #checking
        if check == 3:
            print("Password Validated")
            found = True
        else:
            pss = input("Correct you password")#re enters password
            check = 0
            done = 0
            done2 = 0
```